# How long can you keep bacon (from a butcher) in the refrigerator?

Tags: storage-lifetime, bacon

I bought smoked bacon from a local butcher and I want to know how long I can keep that bacon in the refrigerator. It is an all natural product with no preservatives other than the process by which it was cured, so no nitrates etc. I forgot to ask the butcher thinking it would be gone before it became an issue.

Comment: Smoking bacon is considered a seasoning. Not a cure. There is no real cure in smoking bacon. Per Charcuterie book I own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most cured products last 7-10 days in the fridge although you most likely will see a quality drop off before then at around day three or four.  You can also freeze the bacon for up to two months and thaw for use to extend the shelf life.

Comment: When I freeze my bacon I wrap each one around itself indvidually. This way I can take out just as much bacon as I need. I have also cooked it directly from frozen with success.

Comment: Not all bacon is cured - some is just smoked. I believe this is

Comment: @jefromi smoking is a type of preservation all its own. Depending on your locale, the law might require enough to preserve or not. Either way, all temperature controlled proteins will remain good for ten days under refrigeration regardless of their cured/uncured status. Since the OP specified a local shop, the answer is as correct as I can make it without additional information.

Comment: @sarge_smith: Thanks for the clarification! I've seen bacon in stores that explicitly says "uncured", so the extra information is helpful.

Comment: Even bacon that is marketed as uncured is technically "cured". Check the ingredient list, you will find celery, which is high in nitrites.  See: http://www.meatmythcrushers.com/myths/the-use-of-celery-powder-to-cure-some-meats-is-misleading.html.  One way or another bacon is cured. No nitrates and it is simply smoked pork belly.